# Strange selective packet loss, only when request comes from outside ISP network

Tags: isp

The following issue is having me scratching my head for about two months now...:

When I connect to my home server from a public IP **within my ISP** (i.e. another customer of my ISP) I **suffer sudden drops of connections** (packets do not return). Examples:

- SSH suddenly freezes, especially when stdout holds a lot of information (`cat` of "larger" files, long `ls`, etc).
- HTTP responses come through on tiny pages, larger pages don't.
- Ping works fine, even when setting packet size to max 65515.

When I connect to my home server from a public IP **outside of my ISP** (i.e. someone that's not a customer of the same ISP as I am) **everything works flawlessly** (no remarkable packet loss at all).

I'm struggling to fully diagnose the issue. Is it some evil filtering of the ISP? Is it because of a buggy network topology within my ISP?

What am I missing?

Comment: This is really only something your ISP support can help you with.

Comment: Right, I tried that. Their customers support service is ridiculous. Getting to talk to a *real* technician is a huge gamble and when you finally do, you only get basic responses (of the sort: "Can you reboot your router and try again?").

Comment: Unfortunately that's what you get with a consumer ISP. Upgrade to their business service and you'll have better support options.

Comment: I wish I had the financial means... ;)

Comment: I'm sure! Regardless, you have neither the access needed to diagnose this, nor the capability to fix it, in which case it's off-topic here.

Comment: Keep in mind that running servers on consumer-grade internet access can actually be against the ToS. Meaning, they won't support this kind of access, and may even hinder it.

Comment: @jlehtinen I don't think they can hinder it, as that would also break non-server applications such as games or VoIP that relies on direct connections between peers.

Comment: @AndréDaniel I can guarantee you that if you tried to start, for example, an email hosting company using consumer DSL... the ISP would not simply let it happen. :)

Comment: @jlehtinen sure they may terminate your contract or take legal action if they discover that, but by "hindering" I thought you meant intentionally dropping packets or similar.

Answer (score -1):

Your ISP is waiting anxiously for you to upgrade to their business plan.

Find the minimum months subscription, have them reconfigure your routing QoS, cancel business plan.

Or, less conniving, find a host external to your ISP, setup datapipe/nc/some other port re-director and bounce traffic from your friend's network to yours.